# Removing empty nodes from HTML

Tags: python, html

We are migrating from one content system into another and have tons of HTML where there are lines, for example, like this:

```html
<p style="text-align: justify;"><i> </i></p>
```

I am looking for a way to strip HTML with Python where there is no text output to the screen. So a line similar to this would be stripped.

And, this is just one of MANY examples of lines where there is no text output. So, I would need to find them all to strip. I don't have to worry about images, movies, etc. since only text was possible in our old content management system.

BTW, the vast majority of the lines either start with a `p` tag or a `div` tag (ignoring leading whitespace).

Comment: Hmm. What about structural tags that are empty? (divs for use by JavaScript, e.g.)

Comment: I think you'll need a html parser for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the HTML is also a well-formed XML document (This can be done in a pre-pass with a tool like **[HTML-Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)**), this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space(.))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any such XML document** -- for example:

```
<html>
 <body>
   Welcome.
   <p style="text-align: justify;"><i> </i></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted result in which any element whose string value is empty or is all whitespace, is deleted**:

```
<html>

   <body>
      Welcome.


   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Unix machine, this python script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit("usage: %s HTML_FILE" % sys.argv[0])

stylesheet = '''
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="*[string-length(normalize-space(.)) = 0]"/>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
'''

stylesheet_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.xslt')
stylesheet_file.write(stylesheet)
stylesheet_file.flush()

p = subprocess.Popen("xsltproc --html %s %s" % (stylesheet_file.name, sys.argv[1]), 
        shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p.wait()
sys.stdout.write(p.stdout.read())
stylesheet_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the HTML file isn't valid XHTML, I suggest installing the beautifulsoup4 and lxml packages and using the following script, which removes all tags without text contents and then throws away empty lines from the output:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element
def no_nl(s):
    return str(s).replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print "Usage: %s html_file > output" % sys.argv[0]
    sys.exit(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1]))

# first we have to get rid of all comments
for e in soup.find_all():
    for x in e.children:
        if isinstance(x, element.Comment):
            x.replace_with("")

for e in soup.find_all():
    if not len(no_nl(e.text).strip()):
        e.extract()

for s in str(soup).split("\n"):
    if len(s.strip()):
        print s
```

The following HTML:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title>
</head><body>
<div class="abc"><div> 
<div><div><span> </span>
</div><![CDATA[ This should vanish from output ]]> </div>
</div></div><p class="title"> <!--blah blah blah comment to remove-->
<p class="title"><b>Something</b> here.
</p><p style="text-align: justify;">aaa<I> x</I><span>blah</span></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;"><I> </I><span></span>
<p><i><b>  </b></i></p>
<div style="text-align: justify;"><i> </i></div>
<p class="txt">Spam, spam, lovely spam.
<p>    </p></body></html>
```

gets printed as:

```
<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>
<p class="title"><b>Something</b> here.
</p><p style="text-align: justify;">aaa<i> x</i><span>blah</span></p>
<p class="txt">Spam, spam, 
lovely spam.</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()[normalize-space(.)]|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```